# How to generate all permutations of a combination of two vectors based on a specified sequence?

Tags: r, permutation

I am trying to create a list of all possible permutations of the combination of values from S with values from G based on a specific number of repetitions. For example 4 repetitions would look like: SGSGSGSG

```
S <- c("TCT", "TCC", "TCG", "TCA", "AGT", "AGC")
G <- c("GGT", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG")
```

Using the values from the vectors, some example combination would be:

```
"TCTGGTTCTGGTTCTGGTTCTGGT"
"TCTGGTTCCGGCTCGGGATCAGGG"
```

I have found that I can make permutations of each vector independently with the gtools package but this is not really what I'm looking for:

```
pS <- gtools::permutations(v = S, n = length(S), r = 4, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
pG <- gtools::permutations(v = G, n = length(G), r = 4, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
```

Is there a fast way to make all permutations the way I described without the use of a for loop?

I have looked at 'expand.grid()', however, I don't know of a way to restrict this function to giving me only the permutations that consist of SGSGSGSG...

Comment: are u looking for `do.call(expand.grid, list(S, G, S, G, S, G, S, G))`? To generalize it further, you can use `do.call(expand.grid, c(replicate(4, list(S, G))))`

Answer (score 1):

It may be more efficient to use `permuteGeneral`

```
library(RcppAlgos)
permuteGeneral(S, m = length(S), freqs = rep(4, length(S)))
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it's not clear to me how to apply this function to getting the permutations of SGSGSGSG where one element of 'S' is combined with one element of 'G' 4 times. Does this function do something different than 'gtools::permutations()' or just more efficient?